# How to revert back to a Windows only setup from Ubuntu/Windows dual boot?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, multi-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Returning from Dual-boot to just Windows…](https://superuser.com/questions/1138/returning-from-dual-boot-to-just-windows)

Like the title states. Is there an easy way to go back to my Windows only setup and remove the Ubuntu partitions?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to:

1. Format your Ubuntu partitions and reclaim them for Windows 7 drives
2. Set your boot loader to default to Windows 7 with no delay
3. Remove Ubuntu from the boot loader.

The formating can be done with the disk manager in Windows 7.  Without knowing which boot loader you're using I can't give details on the second and third.

XP instructions on doing 2&3 can be found here.  They may or may not work with 7: [How to uninstall linux in dual boot installed with windows xp](https://superuser.com/questions/68990/how-to-uninstall-linux-in-dual-boot-installed-with-windows-xp)